# How to compare the first element of each row within two lists and show any differences

Tags: python

Please correct me if I have worded this incorrectly.

I have two lists of rows from an SQL table. list_2 & list_4. The first element of the row contains the ID. I want to check if list_4 contains any of the IDs from list_2 and if it doesn't then to append the list_2 row to a new list (list_5) with these results. So if all the IDs from List_2 are already in List_4, then list_5 would be empty.

list_2:

```
for row in list_2:
print(row)
```

Output:

```
(150714, 'a:1:{i:0;s:13:"Crowd Chamber";}', 1230, 72108103, datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 17, 12, 46))
(150716, 'a:1:{i:0;s:14:"VocAlign Ultra";}', 1230, 72112640, datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 17, 13, 0, 9))
(150748, 'a:1:{i:0;s:13:"Crowd Chamber";}', 1230, 72112650, datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 17, 13, 3, 41))
```

list_4:

```
for row in list_4:
print(row)
```

Output:

```
(150713, 'Option 1', 1205, 72108103, datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 17, 12, 46), '')
(150715, 'Option 1', 1205, 72112640, datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 17, 13, 0, 9), '')
(150747, 'Option 1', 1205, 72112650, datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 17, 13, 3, 41), '')
(150747, 'a:1:{i:0;s:13:"Crowd Chamber";}', 1230, 72108103, datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 17, 12, 46), '')
(150747, 'a:1:{i:0;s:14:"VocAlign Ultra";}', 1230, 72112640, datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 17, 13, 0, 9), '')
(150747, 'a:1:{i:0;s:13:"Crowd Chamber";}', 1230, 72112650, datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 17, 13, 3, 41), '')
(150748, 'a:1:{i:0;s:13:"Crowd Chamber";}', 1230, 72112650, datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 17, 13, 3, 41), '')
(150716, 'a:1:{i:0;s:14:"VocAlign Ultra";}', 1230, 72112640, datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 17, 13, 0, 9), '')
(150715, 'Option 1', 1205, 72112640, datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 17, 13, 0, 9), '')
(150747, 'Option 1', 1205, 72112650, datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 17, 13, 3, 41), '')
(150713, 'Option 1', 1205, 72108103, datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 17, 12, 46), '')
(150714, 'a:1:{i:0;s:13:"Crowd Chamber";}', 1230, 72108103, datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 17, 12, 46), '')
```

Current code:

```
for x in list_2:
    for y in list_4:
        if x[0]==y[0]:
            print("Match")
        else:
            print("No match")
            list_5.append(x)
            
print(list_5)
```

But of course `y[0]` won't match all the `x[0]` loops so I'm just collecting all the rows when I want to only be collecting the updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait to have iterated on the whole `list_4` before deciding if you've seen it or not. Then use `for/break/else` pattern  : you go in the `else` if no `break` has been used

```
list_5 = []
for x in list_2:
    for y in list_4:
        if x[0] == y[0]:
            break
    else:
        list_5.append(x)
```

But a more performant way would be to extract the IDs in a `set` then just look into it

```
ids = {y[0] for y in list_4}
list_5 = []
for x in list_2:
    if x[0] not in ids:
        list_5.append(x)
```

Comment: Thank you. I've had a long day and my brain just wasn't processing this. I thought that if I had the 'break' that this would end the 'for y' loop and then append list_5 with the last known x value, which would have been the wrong one (x[0] == y[0]). You've then suggested extracting the IDs, but I need to keep the rest of the row in the list_5 not just [0].

Comment: @George the ID extraction allows to save the whole line, see my edi, it's a different thing